# useState in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a useState in a function and I would need to read the state inside a const outside of the function in the same component.

Don't use Redux the project.

Some help?

Comment: Please add some code samples. And be clear about your question. So I can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the state variable values between the functional components using props.

For Example:

```
// Example1 Functional Compoent.
const Example1 = () => {
 const [stateData, setStateData] = useState<any>('Example Value');
 return (
  <>
   <Example2 [stateData]={stateData} />
  </>
 );
}

// Example2 Functional Compoent.
const Example2 = (props: any) => {
 console.log(props.stateData); // you will get the stateData from Example here.
 return (
  <>
   <p> { props.stateData } </p>
  </>
 );
}
```